# Error trying to get drawables resource programmatically

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and java. I am trying to get an image from my drawables folder to show up in the app programmatically. However, `getIdentifier()` is always a null object reference.

When I run this code.

```
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("image", "drawable", getPackageName()); //error here
System.out.println(imageResource); //doesn't get to this
```

The whole app crashes and I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: net.mobiledevelopment.app, PID: 6663
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.mobiledevelopment.app/net.mobiledevelopment.app.Shop}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

I am declaring these variables outside of any function.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do You have Your image in `res\drawables`? And what do You want to do with it? Set it to `ImageView`?

Comment: And when do You call this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works now.

I wasn't calling getResources() inside of the onCreate() method. This is important apparently.